# How can I get my URL to update to different API id's once I've looped through a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, api

When I'm looping through my JSON file I'm taking out all the Ids with this forEach loop

```
var gameId = request("https://api.sportradar.us/ncaamb-t3/games/" + yyyy + "/" + mm + "/" + dd + "/schedule.json?api_key=************", function(error, response, body){
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
      data.games.forEach((v) => {
        console.log(v.id);
      });
    }
});
```

It gives me the ID's of the information that I want like this

```
dcb9a3df-a350-4fa3-ba8d-ddb413a5c5df
c4aa937a-0676-4395-856d-5b7e2216027c
91b8cea3-d41d-4269-aac7-b94e4b06d27c
6043b675-64b7-4575-bc0f-1af1502eb366
56083249-a870-40f7-9d86-f221c588d31c
6f0e4992-d5cc-4e40-ba7f-08cf8f801295
a4ca2161-bbcd-4423-8a51-e5886873e78a
1b9cd7bc-8970-4c62-ae72-c03f93cb2c05
21f9601e-db34-4c30-a568-b40f40627e66
0ccb6184-7abc-4035-ad14-6b2c405ee002
7618e36d-4191-4be1-8cdd-61087df2b07b
793e0d40-4f34-462e-ae0c-fde5c0e0aec3
a7da9ccc-80a1-44f8-b8eb-93369f8e8aae
eb02bcae-83f2-4d00-98be-3add44be7c51
a8fd9234-1b37-4b18-abea-f33afcda0ae0
ad536204-057a-4fe6-8f3d-c151018867af
b4c96280-9799-4566-a36e-9c4ac2fb942b
ed0bdb48-3a3b-47f4-b84c-3cdea0122c9e
0a1276d6-0c5d-4c77-9a3c-de6f04a2f342
b9e451c9-e978-40af-b6cf-bcb21f33aec6
c16b8327-5994-45a7-b380-03e1712e6a0c
6a02a4f5-983a-494b-82a8-bd8155256fd8
c0c3061e-814c-4869-ac66-5bbeb8a59830
9a778f37-1010-4625-b715-a7a0222df673
ddcd9846-c8b7-46d5-87c9-526d0431dc13
c75b0bd5-db16-4f8a-81d1-b8e82e7f2dc9
426f3858-a2b0-462c-a72e-57bc5db32a2f
d2cfb022-064b-4fac-ad99-67666ef25a2d
36ced72a-9d6a-47fe-af0b-613f30ac69c0
```

But then I would like to insert each ID that is returned into a new URL like this:

```
request("https://api.sportradar.us/ncaamb-t3/"+ gameId +"/boxscore.json?api_key=***************", function(error, response, body) {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        var homeName = (data.home.name);
        var awayName = (data.away.name);
        var homeScore = (data.home.points);
        var awayScore = (data.away.points);
        if(homeScore > awayScore){
          console.log(homeName.toUpperCase() + " WIN!");
        }else {
          console.log(awayName.toUpperCase() + " WIN!");
        }
    }

});
```

I'm using the variable gameId inside of my url like this "https://api.sportradar.us/ncaamb-t3/"+ **gameId** +"/boxscore.json?api_key=***************"

But it's only giving me the id's and not what I'm wanting which is whether or not the team won or not. Do you guys have any idea what I could be doing wrong? I need it to visit two different JSON pages.

EDIT******
Tried this out but it didn't seem to work, though it also didn't give me any errors.

```
request("https://api.sportradar.us/ncaamb-t3/games/" + yyyy + "/" + mm + "/" + dd + "/schedule.json?api_key=j6mu95u99hsaayj5etfuzh6w", function(error, response, body){
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
      data.games.forEach((v) => {
        request("https://api.sportradar.us/ncaamb-t3/"+ v.id +"/boxscore.json?api_key=j6mu95u99hsaayj5etfuzh6w", function(error, response, body) {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        var homeName = (data.home.name);
        var awayName = (data.away.name);
        var homeScore = (data.home.points);
        var awayScore = (data.away.points);
        if(homeScore > awayScore){
          console.log(homeName.toUpperCase() + " WIN!");
        }else {
          console.log(awayName.toUpperCase() + " WIN!");
        }
    }

}); 
      });
    }
});
```

When I console.logged it it seems to be working, so I'm not sure why it's not console.logging properly......

```
792e9eff-cece-49bc-a696-a0632702e96e
https://api.sportradar.us/ncaamb-t3/games/792e9eff-cece-49bc-a696-a0632702e96e/boxscore.json?api_key=*********** function (error, response, body) {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        var homeName = (data.home.name);
        var awayName = (data.away.name);
        var homeScore = (data.home.points);
        var awayScore = (data.away.points);
        if(homeScore > awayScore){
          console.log(homeName.toUpperCase() + " WIN!");
        }else {
          console.log(awayName.toUpperCase() + " WIN!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: are you adding the second API call under the forEach loop ?

Comment: you'll need to show how you are calling the second request, because as it stands, you say what you "would like" to do, and state that it's not working. The second snippet uses `gameId` - but that wont be any of those id's, that will be some object that is returned by `request`

Comment: @JaromandaX Ok I'm trying to understand, what I'm trying to do is add in each gameId individually to that URL where the variable gameId is now. I thought I converted the id's to a variable called gameId and that I could use it in my URL

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora Can you explain what you mean a little more, I'm a self taught person who is pretty new to this whole thing.

Comment: Yes, for me sounds like v.id === gameId so, you should be connecting both  somewhere in your code.

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora v.id gives me the id's that I need yes, so I'm wanting to use them in my url, I thought I was connecting them, but apparently not lol how would I connect them?

Comment: Copy the second request inside your foreach loop, bit ideally use Promise.all or similar

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora I think I tried this earlier and it didn't seem to work. I'll try it again. So when I ran it again, it didn't give me anything back but it also didn't give me any errors back.

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora see my edit for what I did.

Comment: Do not assign the request to gameId, and in the second request put v.Id instead gameId

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora Ok I edited the original again to reflect what I'm doing, it's still not console logging what I'm wanting it to. Any other ideas? I'm probably screwing it up somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For the code in your edit--

v.id is the piece of information you want by the looks of it, so in your second API request, you should be concatenating v.id, not gameId.

```
  request("https://api.sportradar.us/ncaamb-t3/"+ v.id +"/boxscore.json?api_key=j6mu95u99hsaayj5etfuzh6w", function(error, response, body) {
```

Comment: Ok I tried editing it but it still doesn't return the console logs that I am looking for. Any ideas? Maybe I'm still screwing it up.

Comment: When you manually insert a game ID into the API call of the second request, does everything work properly?

Comment: No it still doesn't for some reason. However if I run it outside of that foreach loop and get rid of the first loop it works fine.

Comment: Possible problems that come to mind:

JSON value seems normal but is unrecognizable to your code, or formatted slightly wrong.

Or, something's not right with the forEach loop.

Comment: When I run the other request outside the foreach loop it works fine :(

Comment: data.games might not be the right part of the JSON file to reference in your forEach loop then, I'd say. Console log data and take a really close look at it.

Comment: Ok I console logged it so you can see what I'm seeing, right now it seems to be working, it's the second console.log that doesn't seem to want to work. You can see above in my edit.

Comment: Have you console logged the entire JSON object? Usually when I have the sort of problem you're having, it's because there's more layers in between what I'm referencing in my code and what I want to access.